# MediaPlayer not working properly (Android)?

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to make a simple soundboard in android. I am almost done with the hard part, however there still is one problem I need to solve before I can finish the app.

I created a nested switch statement that recognizes an ImageView by it's id, inside that switch statement (so let's say "case R.id.prank") I tell the app what to do when you press the ImageView, the action is up and when the action is down.

now I don't have any problems with the ImageViews or anything, I think it has something to do with the mediaplayer, but i'm not 100% sure. Basically what happens when I press the first ImageView, the first and second sound play. When I press the second button, only the second sound get's played.

I want the first ImageView to play the first sound and the second ImageView to play the second sound. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView bmw_image;
ImageView prank;
MediaPlayer bmw_mp, prank_mp;
int bmw_id;
int prank_id;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prank = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prank);
    bmw_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmw_image);

    bmw_mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dikke_bmw_jongens_cut);
    prank_mp = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.prank_cut);

    bmw_image.setOnTouchListener(this);
    prank.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bmw_image:

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    bmw_mp.start();
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                    view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff777777, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }               
            }
                case R.id.prank:

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                         prank_mp.start();
                            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                            //overlay is black with transparency of 0x77 (119)
                            view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff777777, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            view.invalidate();
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        {
                            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                            view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                            view.invalidate();
                            break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to write `break` for first case so after first sound second will play too .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
ImageView bmw_image;
ImageView prank;
MediaPlayer bmw_mp, prank_mp;
int bmw_id;
int prank_id;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prank = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prank);
    bmw_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmw_image);

    bmw_mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dikke_bmw_jongens_cut);
    prank_mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.prank_cut);

    bmw_image.setOnTouchListener(this);
    prank.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bmw_image: {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    bmw_mp.start();
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                    view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff777777, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case R.id.prank: {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    prank_mp.start();
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                    //overlay is black with transparency of 0x77 (119)
                    view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0xff777777, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: I think I almost got it. I get an error on the last break, it says that the last break is 'an unreachable statement'.

Comment: @VidalSpierings Edited answer helped you or not ? if it helped accept it

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but yes, I got it to work, thanks!

Comment: @VidalSpierings Glad to help you. please accept my answer .